# xml selectNodes not supported using jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml, internet-explorer

I have been tasked with updating a site that was originally written to work only in IE, and making it work cross browser.

I am now getting an error saying:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'selectNodes'

on the output of the ajax call after updating from an IE specific Ajax call to a jquery ajax call that should work cross browser:

Here was the original function that made the call:

```
function XmlHttpRequestBlocking(url, http_type, return_xml, content) {

var http_request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');    
if(http_request == undefined)
    return undefined;
try
{ 
    http_request.open(http_type, url, false);    
    http_request.send(content); 

    if(http_request.status == 403)
    {
        top.location = "Login.aspx";
        return undefined;
    }
    else if (http_request.status == 200) 
    {
        if (return_xml) {
            return http_request.responseXML;
        }
        else {
            return http_request.responseText; 
        }
    }
    else
        return undefined;
}
catch(e)
{
    return undefined;
}

}
```

This was then replaced with:

```
function XmlHttpRequestBlocking(url, http_type, return_xml, content) {

var x;

jQuery.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    async: false,
    success: function (result) {
        x = result;

    }
});

return x;

}
```

And now the following call to the function and attempted parsing of the output produces the error  "Object doesn't support property or method 'selectNodes'" in IE

```
        var capture_station_list = XmlHttpRequestBlocking(g_get_status_url, "GET", true, "");

        var stations = capture_station_list.selectNodes("//channel");
```

I am thinking that the format of the returned xml must be different? attempting to console.log the output of the jquery version shows [object Document] returned.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what is going on:

In the original code, the function returns an [XML DOM object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms534370%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). In the new code, the function returns a jQuery XML Document. The jQuery object doesn't have a selectNodes method. One approach is to rewrite the parsing of the XML so that it uses jQuery. There is a simple example of that [on the jquery parseXML documentation page](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsexml/). In your case it might be something like:

```
  var capture_station_list = XmlHttpRequestBlocking(...);   
  $(capture_station_list).find("channel").each(function(i, station) {
      console.log(station);
      ...
  });
```